# Existence of limit: subsequence of a decreasing "net"

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have  functions $\mu_{\delta}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\delta > 0$. Also, for every $A \in \Omega$, we have that $\mu_{\delta_1}(A) \leq \mu_{\delta_2}(A)$ whenever $\delta_1 \leq \delta_2$. Finally, $\{ \mu_{\delta}: \delta > 0 \}$ is bounded from below.

What I want to show is that, for all $A \in \Omega$,
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \mu_{\delta}(A) $$
exists. If $\delta$ was always an element of $\mathbb{N}$, I could just say that, if we define for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ a_n := \mu_{1/n}(A) $$
then $a_n$ is decreasing in $n$ and bounded from below, hence by the monotone convergence theorem,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{1/n}(A) $$
exists. Now my question is: since 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{1/n}(A) = \lim_{n \to 0} \mu_n(A) $$
can we say 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{1/n}(A) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \mu_{\delta}(A) $$
even though $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

It kind of feels like I'm extracting some kind of "subsequence" (even though I can't turn the $\mu_{\delta}(A)$ into a sequence, but I think it is a net, something I'm not very familiar with), and if a subsequence converges, the sequence need not convergence as well. Taking $\{(-1)^n\}$, we can extract subsequences to which we can apply the monotone convergence theorem, but the sequence itself doesn't converge. The difference, however, between $\{(-1)^n\}$ and $\{\mu_{\delta}(A) : \delta > 0 \}$, is that the former is not increasing/decreasing, but the latter is decreasing as $\delta \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $A\in\Omega$, and define

$$f_A:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R:\delta\mapsto\mu_\delta(A)\;.$$

Then $f_A$ is monotone non-decreasing and bounded below, so

$$\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}f_A(\delta)=\inf f_A[\Bbb R^+]\;.\tag{1}$$

To see this, let $\alpha=\inf f_A[\Bbb R^+]$. If $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta_0>0$ such that $f_A(\delta_0)<\alpha+\epsilon$, and the monotonicity of $f_A$ ensures that $\alpha\le f_A(\delta)\le f_A(\delta_0)<\alpha+\epsilon$ for all $\delta\in(0,\delta_0]$, which is precisely what is meant by $(1)$.

A similar argument shows that

$$\lim_{\delta\to\delta_0^+}f_A(\delta)=\inf\{f_A(\delta):\delta>\delta_0\}$$

for all $\delta_0\ge 0$.